# Meteor ROOT_URL setting to make accounts-facebook work when behind apache proxy

Tags: facebook, apache, proxy, meteor

I'm running meteor on localhost:3000 and I have apache set up to proxy requests for a domain to that meteor instance using a virtualhost and mod_proxy.

I'm getting this error when trying to log in to my meteor app using accounts-facebook:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

I think this is because my ROOT_URL is `http://localhost:3000` . If I change the ROOT_URL to the domain, then of course meteor tries to listen to the domain, but can't because my apache server is in the way.

Is there a way I can make this work without another IP address?

Comment: What if you add `mydomain.com localhost` to your `/etc/hosts` file while you are testing?

Comment: @DavidWeldon , I liked that idea a lot. Just tried it, though, and apache still intercepts the request.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. You can change ROOT_URL to any URL you want. And use 'mrt -p port (dev)' or 'PORT=port mrt (release)' to listen to any port your want. Hope it helps.

Comment: @FlyingFisher, the crux issue is that accounts-facebook needs ROOT_URL to match the actual URL that the client is at because part of the OAuth process is checking that the request comes from a domain allowed in the Facebook developer settings. Because I trying to run on a server that has other websites served by Apache, and the only way to make meteor and Apache share an IP address is to use mod_proxy. So, ROOT_URL needs to be http://localhost for serving purposes, but http://mydomain.com for the purposes of accounts-Facebook. Linode won't give me a second IP address, either (GRRR).

Answer (score 1):

From Meteor documentation,

> Ensure that your $ROOT_URL matches the authorized domain and callback
>   URL that you configure with the external service (**for instance, if you
>   are running Meteor behind a proxy server, $ROOT_URL should be the
>   externally-accessible URL, not the URL inside your proxy**).

In my case, my app is listening on a configured port with mod_proxy behind an Apache proxy server, say it is listening http://www.example.com:8080. I have other applications running on other ports.

To get going, on Facebook I set `Site URL` and `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` to `http://www.example.com:3000` and `App Domains` to `www.example.com`. On my machine I set `ROOT_URL` to `http://www.example.com:3000`, which is externally-accessible.

Such configurations work for me without a second IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I could get it working by simply having

```
# /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
```

And the facebook settings as in the image below. I've set a secondary (mobile) url to point to `http://localhost:3000`

I've created a whole facebook app like this, with login, access to graph-api etc. And everything was working both online and in the dev envrionment

[image]